# Angular 5 - sanitizing HTML with pipe

Tags: angular, angular5, html-sanitizing

When i got the warning:

> "WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content"

I did some research and saw people using the pipe below or a pipe that looks like the one below

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'sanitizeHtml' })
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

    transform(v: string): SafeHtml {
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I still get the same error even when i implement the pipe like this:

```html
<span [innerHTML]="specialist.blocks[0].paragraph.html | sanitizeHtml"></span>
<p [innerHTML]="package.fields.remarks | sanitizeHtml"></p>
<li [innerHTML]="package.fields.name | sanitizeHtml"></li>
```

So I'm wondering if I implemented the pipe wrong or is there something else why it doesn't work?

**Edit:**

example of `specialist.blocks[0].paragraph.html`:

> "< div id="test" class="test"> \n< h3>NAME SPECIALIST<
> /h3>\n< p>random text< /p>< /div>\n< /div>"

example of `package.fields.remarks`:

> "Arrangement: 3 nachten incl. ontbijt en 2 greenfees p.p. met keuze
> uit North en South< br>\n- gratis dagelijkse toegang tot de spa (1 uur
> Hamman, sauna, zwembad, hydromassage)"

example of `package.fields.name`:

> "Shortbreak 3 nachten< br>2 pers./Superior Double/LO, incl. golf"

Getting the warnings in firefox and chrome

Comment: what is the value of `package.fields.remarks` ? can you share in this question

Comment: added value examples

Comment: i have updated my answer can you check this ?. the problem is in the open html tag with space so i just removed the space using pipe it will be working for me

Comment: should have probably said that i put the spaces in there so i could show you  what is in the value because it would use the tags in the question xD

Comment: check the stackblitz link following its working for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjt27k?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: still get the warnings sadly

Comment: Here is a gist https://gist.github.com/MurhafSousli/3d2ddb777c8ce88e2400bd93f694cd3b

Answer (score 8):

As below example if you trying print `{}` in html angular treats it as expression and will give errors so you can got below options,
We have 2 options for HTML sanitization,

1. Using Pipe

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'sanitizeHtml' })
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: string): SafeHtml {
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }

}
```

In Component you can use it as `{{variable | santizeHtml }}`

2. Using Component,
   as an property binding like below,
   Declare html in .ts file

```js
const allowedChars = '@ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ - ., ? < > { } [ ] ! +';
```

and use it in template as,

```html
<span [innerHTML]="allowedChars"></span>
```

Comment: Where is `allowedChars` even used?`Also this is no proper xss-safe sanitisation if you just use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` and is vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Answer (score 3):

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjt27k?file=app%2Fsanitize-html.pipe.ts

pipe.ts

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'sanitizeHtml'})
export class sanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {
    transform(value) {
        return value.split('< ').join('<');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is way too simple and can likely be bypassed.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution should be following [the Angular security guide](https://angular.io/guide/security#direct-use-of-the-dom-apis-and-explicit-sanitization-calls):

> [..] Avoid directly interacting with the DOM and instead use Angular templates where possible.
>
> For cases where this is unavoidable, use the built-in Angular sanitization functions. Sanitize untrusted values with the DomSanitizer.sanitize method and the appropriate SecurityContext. That function also accepts values that were marked as trusted using the bypassSecurityTrust … functions, and does not sanitize them, as described below.

So `DomSanitizer` [explicitly has a `sanitize` method](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#sanitize) intended for this, so you should - in case of doubt - just use this.

E.g. in a pipe like this:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeValue } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'sanitizeHtml' })
export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(untrustedHtml: string): SafeValue {
    return this._sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, untrustedHtml);
  }
}
```

[(**Stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gtnzxs?file=app%2Fsanitize-html.pipe.ts))

Of course, remember that this example here is only to be used **and only secure** with HTML. For CSS sanitisation or so you'd need a different pipe (i.e. just change the [`SecurityContext`](https://angular.io/api/core/SecurityContext)).

Answer (score -2):

- All is good but your HTML is not perfect. so you need to remove space from html tags.
- Your JSON something should be like this

**JSON:**

```
      specialist: any = {
        "blocks": [
          {
            "paragraph": {
              "html": '<div id="test" class="test">\n<h3>NAME SPECIALIST</h3>\n<p>random text</p> <div>\n</div>'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
      package: any = {
        "fields": {
          "remarks": 'Arrangement: 3 nachten incl. ontbijt en 2 greenfees p.p. met keuze uit North en South<br>\n- gratis dagelijkse toegang tot de spa (1 uur Hamman, sauna, zwembad, hydromassage)',
          "name": 'Shortbreak 3 nachten<br>2 pers./Superior Double/LO, incl. golf'
        }
      }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <span [innerHTML]="specialist.blocks[0].paragraph.html | sanitizeHtml"></span>
    <p [innerHTML]="package.fields.remarks | sanitizeHtml"></p>
    <li [innerHTML]="package.fields.name | sanitizeHtml"></li>
```

**Sanitize Pipe TS:**

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    
    @Pipe({ name: 'sanitizeHtml' })
    export class SanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    
        constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    
        transform(v: any): any {
            return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(v);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

[Browser Output Log View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maRAv.png)

For full HTML Sanitizing import setup process see **[this post](https://kknebulatech.blogspot.com/2021/07/how-to-sanitizing-html-with-pipe.html)**

Comment: This is explicitly unsafe (i.e. will result in an XSS), as it just passes untrusted HTML to the `SanitizeHtmlPipe`, which does actually just bypass the security checks via `bypassSecurityTrustHtml`.