# Angular render HTML inside property values

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

message.properties.ts

```
export const message {
'comment.require.error2': 'The response has been chosen as <b>NO</b>, you must provide comments to support it',
}
```

HTML

```
 <small class="lmn-text-danger">
     {{ message['comment.require.error2'] }}
 </small>
```

How can I render `NO` as bold, when I try to use this way it also renders HTML`(<b>NO</b>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `innerHTML` to render string as HTML instead of plain text with string interpolation:

```
 <small class="lmn-text-danger" [innerHTML]="message['comment.require.error2']"></small>
```

Also, as this adds elements to the DOM, which poses security risk, it is advisable to sanitize it with [DOMSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Example using pipe: [Angular 5 - sanitizing HTML with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528311/angular-5-sanitizing-html-with-pipe)